# Does God(s) hate anyone?

Tags: gods, vedanta, dharma, dharma-shastras, goddess

You would think that, because we are so insignificant to them, they would not bother to hate anyone, because humans can never be a threat to them (Gods).

Answer (score 3):

You are right. God doesn't hate anyone. However it's not because of threat. Its a parent-child relationship.

> I am the Supersoul, O Arjuna, seated in the hearts of all living
> entities. I am the beginning, the middle and the end of all beings.(BG
> 10.20)
>
> I envy no one, nor am I partial to anyone. I am equal to all. But
> whoever renders service unto Me in devotion is a friend, is in Me, and
> I am also a friend to him.(BG 9.29)
>
> If one offers Me with love and devotion a leaf, a flower, a fruit or
> water, I will accept it.(BG 9.26)
>
> Those who always worship Me with exclusive devotion, meditating on My
> transcendental form – to them I carry what they lack, and I preserve
> what they have.(BG 9.22)